# Nancy OWIN test interaction

Tags: c#, nunit, owin, autofac, nancy

I'm trying to figure out why our integration tests are not independent.

The essential part of each test is:

```
var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
// IoC registrations, typically SingleInstance lifetimes or RegisterInstance
var browser = new Browser(new CustomBootstrapper(builder));
// browser.Post...
// Assertions
```

Each test uses fresh ContainerBuilder and Browser instances.

One of our tests passes when run independently, but fails if run along with another similar test. This happens in two different test runners (TestDriven.Net and JetBrains).

Instrumenting, I can see by checking HashCodes that an object used by the first test and injected by the IoC container shows up in the second test (and doesn't match the object created there). Methods are called on the wrong object, so the test fails.

The code doesn't use static members.

Am I misunderstanding something about the way Nancy, Nancy.Testing, or OWIN works? How can these tests influence each other?

Per request, more details:

```
[Test]
public void Test1()
{
    var organizationCache = new OrganizationCache();
    // Logs Creating OrganizationCache with HashCode:43641814 (varies by run)
    organizationCache.AddOrganization(organization);
    ContainerBuilder builder = AutofacTestContainerBuilderFactory.CreateTestContainerBuilder();
    builder.RegisterInstance(organizationCache);
    var browser = new Browser(new CustomBootstrapper(builder));

    BrowserResponse browserResponse = browser.Post(
        "/api/...",
        with => with.JsonBody(model));

    browserResponse.StatusCode.ShouldBe(HttpStatusCode.OK);
}
```

In separate TestFixture class, with no setup/teardown on either:

```
[Test]
public void Test2()
{
    var organizationCache = new OrganizationCache();
    // Logs Creating OrganizationCache with HashCode:5337202 (varies by run)
    organizationCache.AddOrganization(organization);
    ContainerBuilder builder = AutofacTestContainerBuilderFactory.CreateTestContainerBuilder();
    builder.RegisterInstance(organizationCache);
    var browser = new Browser(new CustomBootstrapper(builder));

    TestHelpers.Authenticate(browser);  // log in (does a browser.Post)

    BrowserResponse browserResponse = browser.Post(
        "/api/...",
        with => with.JsonBody(model));

    browserResponse.StatusCode.ShouldBe(HttpStatusCode.Created);

    // Passes if run independently, fails if run with other test
    // When run with other test, system under test logs both OrganizationCache HashCodes during this test
}
```

Could CookieBasedSessions somehow be affecting this? (Note: I tried removing `CookieBasedSessions.Enable` and- separately and together- creating a new `Session` in the pipeline; this did not affect the issue.)

Disposing of the customBootstrapper after each test made no difference either.

(`CustomBootstrapper` has no static fields and descends from `AutofacNancyBootstrapper`. It's too long to post here.)

Comment: Are you using a [TearDown](http://nunit.org/index.php?p=teardown&r=2.6.4) to clean up these tests and setup to initialize them or is this sitting in the method?

Comment: Could you show some more code? Ie the unittest that that breaks, and the unittest that makes the otherone break when run togheter? Also the setup and teardown methods if you are using that.

Comment: What @andreasnico says

Comment: @andreasnico and others - please see my edits.

Comment: Where does organization come from, what does TestHelpers.Authenticate look like, how are you using organization in your module, what does your module look like, what does your custom bootstrapper look like, what is the model you are posting look like

Comment: @Jon Organization has nothing to do with this. The issue is that the `OrganizationCache` instance from the first test shows up during the second test run. `TestHelpers.Authenticate` simply does a `browser.Post`. `CustomBootstrapper` has no static fields and descends from `AutofacNancyBootstrapper`. I can't post our entire application here; there are hundreds of lines in the bootstrapper alone. We're just dealing with Nancy modules that use constructor injection though.

Comment: If you have no setup/teardown code & the tests are completely separate then I'm not sure how thats possible as you new up a new container, bstrapper and browser

Comment: @Jon Exactly. That's why this is so frustrating to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of our developers found the issue in our code.

```
using Nancy.Authentication.Forms;

public class UserMapper : IUserMapper
{
    public static IOrganizationService OrganizationService { get; set; }
    // ...
}
```

The implementation of `IOrganizationService` has an `OrganizationCache` injected into its constructor.

The **static** field was the culprit.